# How can I display a msgbox for which page an empty control lies on?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that displays each empty control in a userform and which page it lies on (I also highlight the field). if the user forgets a ton of controls, the msgbox cuts off because of the fixed length. is there a way to turn this code to just state the page name (once) if an empty field lies on it?

example: need to turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

Here is the code I use to collect all of the control names of interest.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim colBlankFields As New Collection, colPageNames As New Collection
    Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control, onePage As MSForms.Page
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strPrompt As String

    For i = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1
        'if statement to check if page already in collection
            colPageNames.Add item:=onePage, key:=oneControl
            For Each oneControl In ControlsOfInterest
                oneControl.BackColor = vbWhite
                If oneControl.Name Like "opt*" Then
                    If Not OptionGroupSelectionMade(oneControl) Then
                        oneControl.BackColor = RGB(255, 128, 128)
                        colBlankFields.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
                        strPrompt = strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption
                     End If
                Else
                If oneControl.Visible And oneControl.Text = vbNullString Then
                        oneControl.BackColor = RGB(255, 128, 128)
                        colBlankFields.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
                        strPrompt = strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption
                    End If
                End If
            Next oneControl
        End If
    Next i
    If colBlankFields.Count <> 0 Then
        MsgBox strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption
    End If
End Sub

Function OptionGroupSelectionMade(oneButton As MSForms.OptionButton) As Boolean
    Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control

    For Each oneControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(oneControl) = "OptionButton" Then
            If oneControl.Parent.Name = oneButton.Parent.Name Then
                If oneButton.GroupName = oneControl.GroupName Then
                    If oneControl.Value Then
                        OptionGroupSelectionMade = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oneControl
End Function
```

initialize event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control
    Dim onePage As MSForms.Page
    ' existing code

    Set ControlsOfInterest = New Collection
    For Each onePage In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
        For Each oneControl In onePage.Controls

            If oneControl.Name Like "txt*" And oneControl.Visible Then
                ControlsOfInterest.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
            ElseIf oneControl.Name Like "opt*" And oneControl.Visible Then
                ControlsOfInterest.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
            ElseIf oneControl.Name Like "cmb*" And oneControl.Visible Then
                ControlsOfInterest.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
            End If

        Next oneControl
    Next onePage
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this multiple ways.

1st: Break your controls into pages. Then iterate through the pages, checking the controls on that page.  When you find an empty control add that page to the list and stop checking the rest of the controls on that page.

2nd: Similiar in flavor to the first, each time you find a control that is blank add the page to the list, if the page is not already in the list.   If the page is already in the list then skip it.

Show the list of pages to the user.

Here's some code based on your updated code.

I would not iterate through the pages unless you have the controls listed in your collection by page.  VBA doesn't allow multi-for loop breaking with exiting, which is annoying.

Here is the concept code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim colBlankFields As New Collection, colPageNames(1) As String
    Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control, onePage As MSForms.Page
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strPrompt As String
    
    colPageNames(0)="No Match"

      For Each oneControl In ControlsOfInterest
          oneControl.BackColor = vbWhite
          If oneControl.Name Like "opt*" Then
              If Not OptionGroupSelectionMade(oneControl) Then
                  'Check here if we have already found a problem on this Page
                  If (UBound(VBA.Filter(colPageNames,oneControl.Parent.Caption))<0) Then 'if page is not in list already
                      oneControl.BackColor = RGB(255, 128, 128)
                      colBlankFields.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
                      strPrompt = strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption
                      colPageNames(Ubound(colPageNames))=oneControl.Parent.Caption 'Add page to array list
                  End If
               End If
          Else
          If oneControl.Visible And oneControl.Text = vbNullString Then
                 If (UBound(VBA.Filter(colPageNames,oneControl.Parent.Caption))<0) Then 'if page is not in list already                  
                    oneControl.BackColor = RGB(255, 128, 128)
                    colBlankFields.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
                    strPrompt = strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption
                    colPageNames(Ubound(colPageNames))=oneControl.Parent.Caption 'Add page to array list
                 End If  
              End If
          End If
          Next oneControl
    
    If colBlankFields.Count <> 0 Then
        MsgBox strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption
    End If
End Sub

Function OptionGroupSelectionMade(oneButton As MSForms.OptionButton) As Boolean
    Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control

    For Each oneControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(oneControl) = "OptionButton" Then
            If oneControl.Parent.Name = oneButton.Parent.Name Then
                If oneButton.GroupName = oneControl.GroupName Then
                    If oneControl.Value Then
                        OptionGroupSelectionMade = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oneControl
End Function
```

Comment: if I take your second approach, I'd just have to change this line in both blocks `colBlankFields.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name`, but unsure how to switch that to add page name. Also, it would still iterate over every control, showing duplicate page names in the message box, right?

Comment: If you check if the page is added first, and if it is don't add it again then no it won't have duplicates.  If you use the first option, having a two dimensional array with pages and then controls in those pages you could break the For loop on iterating further controls for the same page once you've added that page to the problem list.

Comment: 2d array as in for each page loop and then a for each control loop inside that?

Comment: so I added in the components for the second loop, but still a little confused on the if statement to see if page name exists. Can you assist? I have updated my revised code attempt

Comment: getting a subscript out of range error on this line: `If (LBound(Filter(colPageNames, oneControl.Parent.Caption)) < 0)`

Comment: Updated code.   Here is some test code I used in MS Access to veryify:
```
Private Sub Command182_Click()
 Dim myarr(2) As String
  testitL.Caption = "noMatch"
  myarr(1) = "Rick"
  myarr(2) = "Tony"
  testitL.Caption = Str(UBound(VBA.Filter(myarr, "Sam", True, 1))) 
End Sub
```

Comment: From what you've stated I would change the messages to just display the pages.  Such as prompt = "You have empty fields on the page: " & pagename & "Please complete all fields on this page".  

Otherwise you'll only display a prompt for the first empty control you find and you might annoy the users.

Comment: pasted that code back in and still getting the same subscript out of range error. is this because i'm working with an excel userform and not an access userform?

Comment: Yes, initialize the array instead of colPageNames() As String use dim colPageNames(1) as string.  Then set the first as "No Match" ie:  colPageNames(0)="No match" or something that does not equal to a page name.

Comment: I don't even see an array being declared, nor values even being appended to it. I've uploaded the initialize event to see if that helps clarify where i need to edit.

Comment: uploaded the initialize event, what am i changing in there? I just don't even see an array being declared is all

Comment: In the DIM statements at the top of the code
You'll need to add another line to set the first one as a suggested.
Change the line  Dim colBlankFields As New Collection, colPageNames() As String  to 
 Dim colBlankFields As New Collection, colPageNames(1) As String.  Second line of code.
I updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: ok so that solved the prior error, but now getting an object defined error on this line:      `MsgBox strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption` on the `oneControl.Name` part

Comment: Are you getting the error on the first control or after?  I would step through your code using the debugger to see where and what oneControl is set and what it is.

Comment: Getting the error after the whole procedure has been run up until the msgbox part. I stripped away everything but `msgbox strPrompt` and it worked. How can I just show the page names and not the control that triggered the page name in the array? I don't need to display the actual control name, just tell the user to go back to `x` page